# Back to previous activity and not refreshing it

Tags: android

I have a problem and I don't what to do properly.
**MainActivity** performs simple calculations and from MainActivity opens **Activity two**
When I push back button from "Activity two" it opens MainActivity but without again perform the code.


**Solution #1**
Kill MainActivity and again reload when BackButton is pressed?

**Solution #2** 
 function  `onResume()`

Which is better? Maybe some new idea? Thank you.

Comment: This really depends on what you need to happen. If whatever code you are talking about needs to run every time the activity comes to the foreground then just put it in `onResume()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `onResume()` is definitely better and is made to do that. If you used solution 1, it may let your app get slower because you will load it many times from scratch...

Answer (score 0):

It depends what is your final goal but I doubt if solution 1 is a good solution in any case.

If you want to run some code every time your `Activity` is resumed then put your code in `onResume()`;

If you want to run some code only when you get back from `Activity` 2 then you have to start your `Activity` for result and wait for callback in `MainActivity` and run some code based on returned value.

It works like this:
First start Activity for result

```
static final int JUST_AN_ID = 1;

startActivityForResult(secondActivityIntentHere, JUST_AN_ID);
```

In second Activity when you finish, you can return data:

```
Intent intent = this.getIntent();
intent.putExtra("SOME_DATA", "DATA");
this.setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

Lastly in your MainActivity you can get a call back when you Activity 2 is finished with data:

```
@Override 
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request we're responding to 
    if (requestCode == JUST_AN_ID) {
        // Make sure the request was successful 
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
             //do something here
        } 
    } 
}
```